# Can't use any wildcard with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The aim is simple, I have a sequence of GIF files:

```
000000.gif
000001.gif
000002.gif
...
```

I want to make a movie out of them. I tried:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i *.gif output.flv
```

and got "*.gif: Invalid argument" error. Then tried:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %06d.gif output.flv
```

and got "%06d.gif: No such file or directory" error. However trying:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 000006.gif output.flv
```

works fine. I am beginning to think that my ffmpeg build which is the default x86 build for Windows does not support any wildcarding.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not ffmpeg that should expand wildcards but the shell.

Comment: this is windows 7 command prompt. i'm not sure if that shell or bash supports c style wildcarding

Comment: `*.gif` would work in bash. You can run it on Windows via MSYS package or Cygwin.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from this command: `ffmpeg.exe -i %06d.gif output.flv`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following batch:

```
@echo off
set a=
for %%i in (*gif) do call :concat "%%i"
ffmpeg.exe %a% output.flv
goto :eof

:concat
set a=%a% -i %1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks but I get: The input line is too long.
:concat
 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Did you save all that into a batch file (i.e command.bat) ?

Comment: Tested syntax with over 350 files (20 chars long each) but it will break with longer inputs.